# java.io.IOException: Attempted to join a non-multicast group

Tags: java, android, sockets, multicast

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet application.

It has a **MulticastSocket**:

```
public MulticastClient(String serverName, int port, Handler serviceHandler) throws IOException
{
    super(serverName);

    socket = new MulticastSocket(8888);
    InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("203.0.113.0");
    socket.joinGroup(group);

    this.mServiceHandler = serviceHandler; 
}
```

I get an error here:

`InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("203.0.113.0");`

This is the **error**:

`java.io.IOException: Attempted to join a non-multicast group`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It seems like the IP address you are about to access is not a multicast group while your access need it to be a multicast group . I think you'd better ask the server administrator for it .

Comment: The questionable IP, 203.0.113.0, was taken from an official Java tutorial that Oracle wrote/bought: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html. They should correct it!!! I tried "224.0.0.10" and it worked. Thanks @Rawkode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xml), multicast addresses have a strict and enforced range.

> The multicast addresses are in the range 224.0.0.0 through
>   239.255.255.255.

Comment: The questionable IP, 203.0.113.0, was taken from an official Java tutorial that Oracle wrote/bought: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html. They should correct it!!!